# Access rights for admin and users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I launch the project, the page "allStudents.jsp" comes out and on this page the admin must first enter with the help of his login and password. Only admin can edit, add, delete students. But why my students are being edited and deleted without admin input. After all, I put access rights that only admin can delete and edit students.

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}1234").roles("ADMIN");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/allStudents**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/addStudent**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/editStudent/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")



                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll() 
                .and()

                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .successForwardUrl("/allStudents")
                .loginPage("/allStudents")

                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring security works in `@Order` i.e with highest secured point, followed by lesser one. If add/edit/delete students are accessible only to admin you should modify these endpoints as /adminAddStudent and similar. Next modify you security configuration as below

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    { 

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    }
```

`/allStudent` is definitely not a login page as login page contains form with 2 inputs (namely "username" and "password" ) and a submit button

Comment: Can you help me change please

Comment: try modifying your security config as explained in my answer. please let me know what else i can help with

Comment: I chanhed code in question. Can you show my code